# Nested resources and path

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I'd like to nest resources in Ember, but to be able to access them with a short URL.

For example: mysite.com/admin will open the route: /routes/profiles/settings/admin

Is it possible to do something like that using Ember?
I'm currently using Ember 1.7 with Ember App Kit.

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend();

Router.map(function () {
this.resource('profile', function () {
    this.resource('profile.settings', { path: '/settings' }, function () {
        this.resource('profile.settings.admin', { path: '/admin' });
    );
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to repeat the parent route name if you're nesting.  Your nested resource `profile.settings` should be just `settings`, same for `profile.settings.admin`, should be just `admin`.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Not if he wants the route names to be prefixed. He either has to nest `this.route()` calls or he has to add the prefix himself. And it's advisable to have the prefixes so name collisions don't appear with a lot of routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because your inner most resource is inheriting the `/profile` path from the outer most resource and `/settings` from the middle resource. If you want it to be just plain `/admin`, you'd have to do something like this:

```
this.resource('profile', { path: '' }, function() {
    this.resource('profile.settings', { path: '' }, function() {
        this.resource('profile.settings.admin', { path: '/admin' });
    });
});
```

However, this is going to get pretty hairy when you have more routes that each want top-level paths. You might find it easier to just declare a `admin` route at the top level, then redirect using the [redirect](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_redirect) hook in the route.

Comment: This works when you have only one resource at the root level with an empty path. If you have more than one it doesn't work properly.

Comment: That's why I mentioned that you'd probably be better off just redirecting from a top-level route. It's a lot more explicit than this.